# Update data from EditText Listview to firebase database on button click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database like this

[image]

It is possible to first set text of name in Edittext which is in Listview and then change the name to corresponding position items and on button click each inserted value in Editfield is updated to the database to related field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Download:

FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference reference=database.getReference();

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
```

//parse data snapshot in another thread.

```
        }catch (Exception e){






        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {






    }
});
```

//===========================
2- Parse:
  HashMap d = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
HashMap users=((HashMap) d.get("users"));

3- Update ListView/EditText or use users(Hashmap)

4- Update:

```
String nameString= nameEditText.getText().toString();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

// getting database reference for the user that needs to be updated.

```
DatabaseReference  databaseReference = database.getReference().child("users").child(userId);

Map<String, Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        taskMap.put("name", nameString);

        databaseReference.updateChildren(taskMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d("", "task is: " + task);
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Commit is successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Commit is failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Log.d("", "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to save value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have to listview with editText and i want to first populate the data first in each EditText then change the data to correspond position and on submit button click all data which are enter in edittext field is updated to database and thanks for reply

Comment: The basic logic is
1- Download
get firebase database reference and get the datasnapshot.

2- Parse snapshot using hashmap.

3- use that hashmap to display data, the way u want.

4- Update the value by getting the reference to that value.